# When I try to stream my webcam video by using getUserMedia() api a black screen is appearing

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to access the user's webcam by using `navigator.getUserMedia()`. I am assigning the video.srcObject to this stream. But I am getting a black screen on video. 
I event tried with    `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`

```
<video controls id="webcam"></video>
<script>
    const webcam = document.getElementById("webcam"); 
    function startVideo() {
        navigator
            .getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: false
                },
                liveStream => {
                    console.log(liveStream);
                    webcam.setAttribute("controls", 'true');
                    webcam.srcObject = liveStream;
                    webcam.play();
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
    startVideo();
</script>
```

Comment: By all means, use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. What does it mean "converted the stream to a blob"? That's a non sense at best. Where do you get the black screen? In the `<video>` element? Can you get rid of unused code (e.g the canvas and the noop takeSnapshot function) if it is not relevant to the question. And from which browser do you experience this issue? From here that sounds just like a call to play being denied by lack of user gesture.

Comment: Can you also add HTML?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?